# Array of hash for key as variable value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hash. I want to add a value to the hash. I get the variable as a hash key or value. My code is

```
variable = "Test"
array[0] = {"a" => "10"}
array[i-1].merge({"#{variable}" => "60" })
```

I get the hash as `array[0] = [{"a" => "10"}, {"variable" => "60"}]`

I want the hash for variable value like below

```
array[0] = [{"a" => "10"}, {"Test" => "60"}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you describe why you want that structure? Also, what do you want to do with the structure once you have it? Perhaps if you answer those someone may be able to suggest a better structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after. You already have a hash, so just set the key directly.

```ruby
variable = "Test"
array = []
array << {"a" => "10"}
array[0] = [array[0], {variable => "60"}]
```

Based on the comments, it sounds like you're after `array[0] => [{"a" => "10"}, {"Test" => "60"}]`. It seems very strange that `array[0]` would be a hash key *and* part of the value, but this should produce that:

```ruby
variable = "Test"
array = []
array << {"a" => "10"}
{array[0] => [array[0], {variable => "60"}]}
#=> {{"a"=>"10"}=>[{"a"=>"10"}, {"Test"=>"60"}]}
```

Comment: James, OP has asked for 'array[0] => [{"a" => "10"}, {"Test" => "60"}]', not `[{"a"=>"10", "Test"=>"60"}]`. Yes, the question is not very clear.

Comment: It's not even that. Oy. I'm not sure why someone would want a structure like this.

Comment: I want the output as array[0] => [{"a" => "10"}, {"Test" => "60"}]

Comment: Update to produce the desired output (I think).

Comment: But in this way I have to iterate as array.each do |arr| puts arr[0]["a"]  end but I want to iterate as we iterate object like array.each do |arr| puts arr["a"]  end  what changes I have to make to the code so that I can iterate as arr["a"] not arr[0]["arr"]? Thanks in advance